# PHP DOM Cut xml in to pieces and save each child with parent separately

Tags: php, xml, dom

I have next type of XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "dtd">
<root>
    <tag1>
        <1>Name</1>
        <2>Num1</2>
        <3>NumOrder</3>
        <4>test</5>
        <6>line</6>
        <7>HTTP  </7>
        <8>1</8>
        <9></9>
    </tag1>
    <tag2>
        <1>Name</1>
        <2>Num1</2>
        <3>NumOrder</3>
        <4>test</5>
        <6>line</6>
        <7>HTTP  </7>
        <8>1</8>
        <9></9>
    </tag2>
    ...
    <tagN>
        <1>Name</1>
        <2>Num1</2>
        <3>NumOrder</3>
        <4>test</5>
        <6>line</6>
        <7>HTTP  </7>
        <8>1</8>
        <9></9>
    </tagN>
</root>
```

And i need to get root with each child element separately in array saved as HTML:

array = [rootwithchild1,rootwithchild2...N];

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "dtd">
    <root>
          <tagN>
            <1>Name</1>
            <2>Num1</2>
            <3>NumOrder</3>
            <4>test</5>
            <6>line</6>
            <7>HTTP  </7>
            <8>1</8>
            <9></9>
        </tagN>
   </root>
```

For now i make 2 doms, in one i get all child separately, in another i have deleted all child and left only root. At these step i wanted to add each child to root, save as html, delete child, and so on with each child, but this doesn't work.

```
        $bodyNode = $copydoc->getElementsByTagName('root')->item(0);

        foreach ($mini as $value) {
            $bodyNode->appendChild($value);
            $result[] = $copydoc->saveHTML();
            $bodyNode->removeChild($value);
        }
```

**Error** on $bodyNode->appendChild($value);
**Mini** is array of cut child. 
**Lib:** $doc = new DOMDocument();

Can anyone advice how to do this right, maybe better to use xpath or something else..? 
Thanks

Comment: Which library are you using? Never forget to mention such a thing!

Comment: Sorry, $doc = new DOMDocument(); Native PHP DOM library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would simply create a new document that contains only the `root` element and a “fake” initial child:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE test SYSTEM "dtd">
<root>
  <fakechild />
</root>
```

After that, loop over the child elements of the original document – and for each of those perform the following steps:

- import the child node from the original document into the new document using `DOMDocument::importNode`
- replace the current child node of the root element of the new document with the imported node using `DOMNode::replaceChild` with the `firstChild` of the root element as second parameter
- save the new document

(Having the `<fakechild />` in the root element to begin with is not technically necessary, a simple whitespace text node should do as well – but with an *empty* root element this would not work in such a straight fashion, because the `firstChild` would give you NULL in the first loop iteration, so you would not have a node to feed to `DOMNode::replaceChild` as second parameter. Of course you could do additional checks for that and use `appendChild` instead of `replaceChild` for the first item … but why complicate stuff more than necessary.)

Comment: Thank you, my problem was in the importNode, i thought i can use nodes from another dom directly. Also better to replace child, then append and delete it.

Answer (score 0):

DOMNode::getElemementsByTagName() returns a live result. So if you remove the node from the DOM it is removed from the node list as well.

You can iterate the list backwards...

```
for ($i = $nodes->length - 1; $i >= 0; $i--) {
  $node = $nodes->item($i);
  ...
}
```

...  or copy it to an array:

```
foreach (iterator_to_array($nodes) as $node) {
  ...
}
```

Node lists from DOMXpath::evaluate() are not affected that way. XPath allows a more specific selection of nodes, too.

```
$xpath = new DOMXpath($domDocument);
$nodes = $xpath->evaluate('/root/*');
foreach (iterator_to_array($nodes) as $node) {
  ...
}
```

But I wonder why are you modifying (destroying) the original XML source?

If would create a new document to act as a template and. Never removing nodes, only creating new documents and importing them:

```
// load the original source
$source= new DOMDocument();
$source->loadXml($xml);
$xpath = new DOMXpath($source);

// create a template dom
$template = new DOMDocument();
$parent = $template;
// add a node and all its ancestors to the template
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/part[1]/ancestor-or-self::*') as $node) {
  $parent = $parent->appendChild($template->importNode($node, FALSE));
}

// for each of the child element nodes
foreach ($xpath->evaluate('/root/part/*') as $node) {
  // create a new target
  $target = new DOMDocument();
  // import the nodes from the template
  $target->appendChild($target->importNode($template->documentElement, TRUE));
  // find the first element node that has no child element nodes
  $targetXpath = new DOMXpath($target);
  $targetNode = $targetXpath->evaluate('//*[count(*) = 0]')->item(0);
  // append the child node from the original xml
  $targetNode->appendChild($target->importNode($node, TRUE));

  echo $target->saveXml(), "\n\n";
}
```

Demo: https://eval.in/191304

Comment: I have made 2 different Doms:
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc2 = new DOMDocument();
and destroy child in one, to get a parent without child, so i can to insert child from second list, save to html, delete this child, insert next and so on.